# In CSS, is it possible to select the last element before a wrap?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example,

I have a bunch of div's side by side, and each div has a border-right:1px

The parent element is a certain width so at a certain point, the extra div wraps to the next line.

In essence, I do NOT want a border-right for the last div before the wrap.

If this doesn't make sense, I can create a fiddle.  I just want to know can I target that last div before the wrap. (last-child will target the last div that is on the next line which isn't want.)

Comment: It does make sense, but create a fiddle anyway. I want to know how you display the divs side by side; with float, display:inline-block, etc?

Comment: Anyway, my gut feeling says it will be easier to give the divs a border-left, and then to hide that border on the left side of the container.

Comment: @MrLister Wouldn't that cause the same issue except now we are trying to find the first child of each dynamically formed row? Unless you are planning to hide that border into the container by giving it a negative margin left? But it is possible that the border need to be on the right in which case border left would not work on the last element before the wrap

Comment: @Huangism No.  If all elements are shifted to the left the same width as the border (and the parent element has hidden overflow), then it's all evened out (see solution below).

Comment: @cimmanon Yea I know it will all even out but if we do that then there won't be a border on the right side of the last element before the wrap

Comment: Are you talking about a fluid width of the parent container that changes with the viewport, or just an uncertain number of child elements?

Comment: @KingKongFrog: Could you create a fiddle for this? This seems like an easy fix. I want to see how you've designed the width of the parent and the child divs.

Answer (score 5):

Figure out how many columns you're getting with the current width, either hardcoded or with JS and then use the `nth-child` selector.

For example if you have 3 columns per row with each `div` having a class of `col` it would be

```
div.col:nth-child(3n){border-right:none;}
```

The nth-child selector can be modified depending on however many columns are in each row of `div`s.

Comment: If they have irregular widths he could just attach a css class with the same idea. With a little JS he could target each end-cap div and place the class on it

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to select the last item from multiple lines, only the `:last-child`.

If your elements line up in columns, the multi-column module may be of interest to you.  It has a column-rule property that's similar to borders, but only appears vertically between columns, never on the outer edges.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/febtiiet

```
.container {
  columns: 20em;
  column-rule: 1px solid;
}
```

Prefixes may be required:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Otherwise, you will need to switch to placing the border on the left as MrLister suggests:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/f8qjngd4

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  border-style: none;
}

.child {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20em;
}
```